# Error: Main method not found in class Checker, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)

Tags: java

I have a project that compiles. However, it returns an error message in the subject line.

```
Error: Main method not found in class, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Any ideas where to edit the `public static void main(String[] args)` into my java project?

Comment: Java != Javascript. And error is clear, you need to define main method for your class to run. Please take time to read basic java tutorials.

Comment: Sorry - Its Java code

Answer (score 1):

The *main* method is a special method that serves as the externally exposed entrance point by which a Java program (Java is *not* Java Script) can be run.  It's declared like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Look - I wrote some Java code!");
    }
}
```

You should seriously take a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html).